# Error in Urban Airship Rich Push Notification Android

Tags: android, urbanairship.com, richpush

I have downloaded Android Rich Push Notification sample code. I have made necessary changes which were described in sample tutorial.

I am beginner to work on Urban Airship.
My Android Manifest file is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:amazon="http://schemas.amazon.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.jpc.urbanairship.richpush.sample"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">

    <!-- minSdkVersion sets runtime compatibility ("will run on API level 9") -->
    <!-- targetSdkVersion should be set to the latest version tested, to disable compatibility modes -->
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="6" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <!-- REQUIRED for Urban Airship -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />  <!-- Required for Push -->

    <!-- MODIFICATION REQUIRED - Replace "com.urbanairship.richpush.sample" with your package name -->
    <permission android:name="com.jpc.urbanairship.richpush.sample.permission.UA_DATA" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.jpc.urbanairship.richpush.sample.permission.UA_DATA" />
    <!-- The two elements above ensure that only this application has access to the Urban Airship provider and can receive push intents -->

    <!-- REQUIRED PERMISSIONS for GCM -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <!-- This app has permission to register with GCM and receive message -->
    <!-- Required MODIFICATION REQUIRED - Replace "com.urbanairship.richpush.sample" with your package name -->
    <permission android:name="com.jpc.urbanairship.richpush.sample.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.jpc.urbanairship.richpush.sample.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <!-- The two elements above ensure that only this application can receive the messages and registration result -->

    <!-- REQUIRED PERMISSIONS for ADM -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.amazon.device.messaging.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <!-- Required MODIFICATION REQUIRED - Replace "com.urbanairship.richpush.sample" with your package name -->
    <permission android:name="com.jpc.urbanairship.richpush.sample.permission.RECEIVE_ADM_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.jpc.urbanairship.richpush.sample.permission.RECEIVE_ADM_MESSAGE" />
    <!-- The two elements above ensure that only this application can receive the messages and registration result -->

    <!-- OPTIONAL Urban Airship Settings -->
    <!-- REQUIRED FOR LOCATION -->
    <!-- Use ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION if GPS access is not necessary -->
    <!-- uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" /-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <!--  OPTIONAL - This permission is only necessary if your app has multiple processes -->
    <!--  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" /> -->

    <application
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/ua_launcher"
        android:name="com.jpc.urbanairship.richpush.sample.RichPushApplication"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">

        <service android:name="com.urbanairship.richpush.RichPushUpdateService"/>

        <activity android:name="com.jpc.urbanairship.richpush.sample.MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.jpc.urbanairship.richpush.sample.inbox.InboxActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.jpc.urbanairship.richpush.sample.preference.PushPreferencesActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.jpc.urbanairship.richpush.sample.inbox.MessageActivity" />

        <!-- Optional: This is an example of one of the many ways to handle deep
        linking in the application.  To use with your application, update the data
        scheme to be unique for the application and modify ParseDeepLinkActivity.parseDeepLink
        method to match your application's deep link parsing -->
        <activity android:name="com.jpc.urbanairship.richpush.sample.ParseDeepLinkActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <!-- Handles any vnd.urbanairship.richpush://deeplink URI's -->
                <data
                    android:scheme="vnd.urbanairship.richpush" android:host="deeplink" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- The provider is needed for the RichPush Widget -->
        <receiver android:name="com.jpc.urbanairship.richpush.sample.widget.RichPushWidgetProvider">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <!-- This specifies the widget provider info -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/widgetinfo" />
        </receiver>

        <!-- The service serving the RemoteViews to the collection widget -->
        <service
            android:name="com.jpc.urbanairship.richpush.sample.widget.RichPushWidgetService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_REMOTEVIEWS"
            android:exported="false" />

        <!-- OPTIONAL, if you want to receive push, push opened and registration completed intents -->
        <!-- Replace the receiver below with your package and class name -->
        <receiver android:name="com.jpc.urbanairship.richpush.sample.PushReceiver"
                  android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.urbanairship.push.CHANNEL_UPDATED" />
                <action android:name="com.urbanairship.push.OPENED" />
                <action android:name="com.urbanairship.push.RECEIVED" />

                <!-- MODIFICATION REQUIRED - Use your package name as the category -->
                <category android:name="com.jpc.urbanairship.richpush.sample" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>


        <!-- REQUIRED for ADM - You must explicitly enable ADM and declare whether your app cannot work without
        ADM (android:required="true") or can work without ADM (android:required="false").
        If you specify android:required="false", your app must degrade gracefully if ADM
        is unavailable. -->
        <amazon:enable-feature
            android:name="com.amazon.device.messaging"
            android:required="false" />

        <!-- REQUIRED for Google Play services (GCM)-->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />


        <!-- Needed for Action.startActivityForResult -->
        <activity android:name="com.urbanairship.actions.ActionActivity" />

        <activity android:name="com.urbanairship.CoreActivity" />

        <!-- REQUIRED for Landing Pages
        MODIFICATION REQUIRED:
         - Set or Remove the parent activity
         - Set or Remove the theme.  Removing the theme will cause the landing page
         to use the default theme for the application.  If the theme allows an action
         bar and is running on a honeycomb or newer device, the action bar will enable
         up navigation.
         - For more customization details, see com.urbanairship.actions.LandingPageActivity -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.urbanairship.actions.LandingPageActivity"
            android:parentActivityName="com.jpc.urbanairship.richpush.sample.MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/LandingPage"
            android:exported="false">

            <!-- Sample layout, remove to use the default -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.urbanairship.action.LANDING_PAGE_VIEW"
                android:resource="@layout/landing_page_activity" />

            <!-- Optional: Landing page will start the parent activity if the landing
            page is the root task.  Also supports proper up navigation if the action
            bar is supported -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.urbanairship.richpush.sample.MainActivity" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.urbanairship.actions.SHOW_LANDING_PAGE_INTENT_ACTION" />
                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- REQUIRED for PlayServiceUtils.handleAnyPlayServicesError to handle Google Play services recoverable errors. -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.urbanairship.google.PlayServicesErrorActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

        <!-- REQUIRED for Urban Airship Push. The priority is important to be set lower than the
               application's push intent receiver in order for the push intent receiver to handle push intents
               before the core receiver. This allows the application to launch any activities before Urban
               Airship performs any actions or falls back to launching the application launch intent. -->
        <receiver android:name="com.urbanairship.CoreReceiver"
                  android:priority="-999"
                  android:exported="false">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.urbanairship.push.OPENED" />

                <!-- MODIFICATION REQUIRED - Use your package name as the category -->
                <category android:name="com.jpc.urbanairship.richpush.sample" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- REQUIRED for GCM -->
        <receiver
            android:name="com.urbanairship.push.GCMPushReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <!-- MODIFICATION REQUIRED - Use your package name as the category -->
                <category android:name="com.jpc.urbanairship.richpush.sample" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- REQUIRED for ADM -->
        <receiver
            android:name="com.urbanairship.push.ADMPushReceiver"
            android:permission="com.amazon.device.messaging.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.amazon.device.messaging.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <action android:name="com.amazon.device.messaging.intent.RECEIVE" />

                <!-- MODIFICATION REQUIRED - Use your package name as the category -->
                <category android:name="com.jpc.urbanairship.richpush.sample" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- REQUIRED for Urban Airship -->
        <service android:name="com.urbanairship.push.PushService" android:label="Push Notification Service" />
        <service android:name="com.urbanairship.analytics.EventService" android:label="Event Service" />
        <service android:name="com.urbanairship.actions.ActionService" />
        <service android:name="com.urbanairship.richpush.RichPushUpdateService" />

        <!-- OPTIONAL for Urban Airship Location (for segments support) -->
        <service android:name="com.urbanairship.location.LocationService" android:label="Segments Service" />

        <!-- This is required for persisting preferences related to push and location -->
        <!-- MODIFICATION REQUIRED - Replace "com.urbanairship.richpush.sample" with your package name -->
        <provider
            android:name="com.urbanairship.UrbanAirshipProvider"
            android:authorities="com.jpc.urbanairship.richpush.sample.urbanairship.provider"
            android:permission="com.jpc.urbanairship.richpush.sample.permission.UA_DATA"
            android:exported="true"
            android:multiprocess="true" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I have not made any change in the MainActivity.java file.
Here is th MainActivity file:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
ActionBar.OnNavigationListener {

    ArrayAdapter<String> navAdapter;
    RichPushUser user;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
        this.configureActionBar();

        this.user = UAirship.shared().getRichPushManager().getRichPushUser();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        setIntent(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // Handle any Google Play services errors
        if (PlayServicesUtils.isGooglePlayStoreAvailable()) {
            PlayServicesUtils.handleAnyPlayServicesError(this);
        }

        // Activity instrumentation for analytic tracking
        Analytics.activityStarted(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // Activity instrumentation for analytic tracking
        Analytics.activityStopped(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setNavigationToMainActivity();

        // Show a message dialog if the pending message id is not null
        String pendingMessageId = getIntent().getStringExtra(RichPushApplication.EXTRA_OPEN_MESSAGE_ID);
        if (!UAStringUtil.isEmpty(pendingMessageId)) {
            getIntent().removeExtra(RichPushApplication.EXTRA_OPEN_MESSAGE_ID);
            showRichPushMessage(pendingMessageId);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        this.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.preferences:
            this.startActivity(new Intent(this, PushPreferencesActivity.class));
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {
        String navName = this.navAdapter.getItem(itemPosition);
        if (RichPushApplication.HOME_ACTIVITY.equals(navName)) {
            // do nothing, we're here
        } else if (RichPushApplication.INBOX_ACTIVITY.equals(navName)) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, InboxActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            this.startActivity(intent);
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Displays the rich push message in a RichPushMessageDialogFragment
     * @param messageId The specified message id
     */
    private void showRichPushMessage(String messageId) {
        RichPushMessageDialogFragment message = RichPushMessageDialogFragment.newInstance(messageId);
        message.show(this.getSupportFragmentManager(), "message");
    }

    /**
     * Configures the action bar to have a navigation list of
     * 'Home' and 'Inbox'
     */
    private void configureActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = this.getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);

        this.navAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.support.v7.appcompat.R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                RichPushApplication.navList);
        actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(this.navAdapter, this);
    }

    /**
     * Sets the action bar navigation to show 'Home'
     */
    private void setNavigationToMainActivity() {
        int position = this.navAdapter.getPosition("Home");
        getSupportActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
    }
}
```

I am facing this problem when I run the sample code:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.urbanairship.R$string
at com.urbanairship.push.NotificationActionButtonGroupFactory.createUrbanAirshipGroups(NotificationActionButtonGroupFactory.java:40)

at com.urbanairship.push.PushManager.<init>(PushManager.java:198)

at com.urbanairship.push.PushManager.<init>(PushManager.java:186)
```

Please help me to get the solution.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell directly from your question if you are using Eclipse or Android Studio, but I had this problem with Android Studio.

I had been including the urbanairship-lib-x.x.x.jar file in the libs folder of my project, but this was producing the same errors that you experienced, even though compilation was fine.

What I did instead:

1. Removed the jar from my libs folder.
2. Followed the Android Studio instructions from http://docs.urbanairship.com/build/push/android.html. Condensed: Add these repositories/dependencies to your build.gradle:

```groovy
repositories {
    mavenCentral()

    flatDir {
        dirs 'aars'
    }
}

...

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.+'
    compile 'com.urbanairship:urbanairship-lib:+@aar'
}
```

3. Finally, since the build.gradle will be looking for a top-level directory 'aars', create one at the root of your project and instead insert the urbanairship-lib-x.x.x.aar (not the jar). The aar file is located in the ua-android-lib-latest.zip you downloaded for the sample tutorial.

I am unfamiliar with any solution using Eclipse, unfortunately.